# Cloud run service-to-service connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have to services (b & c) that i want to connect together via a api request. Service B send the request to service C.

Both services are connected to the same VPC via a VPC Connector. Both are set to route all traffic via the VPC. Service C's ingress is set to allow internal traffic only. Service B's ingress is set to all. Both allow unauthenticated.

When I send a request to B which should forward it to C the request is send but ends up in an error with message `connect ETIMEDOUT {ip}:443`

The code that sends the request:

```
    const auth = new GoogleAuth();
    const url = process.env.SERVICE_C;

    const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(url);
    const clientHeaders = await client.getRequestHeaders();

    const result = await axios.post(process.env.SERVICE_C, req.body, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': clientHeaders['Authorization'],
      },
    });
```

The env variable is the url of service c

What did I not configure correctly yet?

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you call the service C? And did you try with an ingress all on the service C? Does it work?

Comment: Yes ingress all on service C does work. But we want it to not be publicly accessable. Edited the question whit the code of the request.

Comment: you can remove the IdToken from your code, if you deploy unauthenticated service. The error is strange. The connection timeout shouldn't occur. A 403 http error, why not, but here, it's like a bug!! IP is not used by Cloud Run, only URL.

Comment: Review the error message. Is the IP address a private or public IP address?

Comment: I can not find the IP address of the cloud run services.

Comment: I don't know if, in your question, the `{ip}` is redacted or not. It's not clear. But the issue is strange enough to contact Google about that.

Comment: Yes I redacted it just to be sure about security. Alright thanks I will try that.

Comment: I recreated the network and connector and now it all works fine.

Comment: Hey there @BartKalkman , might I recommend putting what you did in an answer and accepting your own answer so that other people may find this if they've had a similar (or the same) issue?

Comment: Hey Bart, Please help. I am facing a very similar issue. But I am not able to what I need to do. I am using App Engine with a VPC Access Connector to connect to Redis. The Redis connections work fine but the access to some APIs is getting blocked